# intercambio de valores

Tags: r

Me gustaría intercambiar los números cuando los datos de una columna  son mayores que los datos de otra columna, por ejemplo

```
datos2<-data.frame(
  col1=c(5,22,9,13,56,11,12),
  col2=c(7,2,2,34,16,23,23))
```

Todos los datos de la col2 deberían ser mayores que los de la col1

```
  col1 col2
1    5    7
2   22    2  (22 > 2, en la col1 debería aparecer 2 y en col2 el 22)
3    9    2  (9 > 2, deberían de intercambiarse)
4   13   34
5   56   16   (56 > 16, deberían de intercambiarse)
6   11   23
7   12   23
```

Mediante bucles se me ha ocurrido algo así, (pero da fallo)

```
for (i in 1:nrow(datos2))
  {
  if ( datos2$col1[i]>datos2$col2[i] )
  
  numero<-datos2$col1[i]
  datos2$col1[i]<-datos2$col2[i]

  datos2$col2[i]<-numero
  }
```

Aparte de que el algoritmo está mal, seguramente hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin usar bucles.

¿Alguien la conoce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede sin bucles, pero es necesario trabajar con columnas/variables auxiliares:

```
datos2$col1b <- ifelse(datos2$col1>datos2$col2, datos2$col2, datos2$col1)
datos2$col2b <- ifelse(datos2$col1>datos2$col2, datos2$col1, datos2$col2)
datos2

 col1 col2 col1b col2b
1    5    7     5     7
2   22    2     2    22
3    9    2     2     9
4   13   34    13    34
5   56   16    16    56
6   11   23    11    23
7   12   23    12    23
```

Con el dos `ifelse()` logramos intercambiar los valores entre ambas colunas, solo resta eliminar las columnas originales y renombrar las nuevas:

```
datos2 <- setNames(datos2[, c(3,4)], c('col1', 'col2'))
```

Otra forma, aunque algo engañosa, por que es un bucle implícito es ordenando por cada fila las dos columnas, aunque aquí terminas con una matriz que deberías reconvertir al `data.frame` original.

```
t(apply(datos2[, 1:2], 1, FUN = function(x) sort(x)))
```

Otra forma, es usar `pmax()` y `pmin()` para generar la columna con los máximos y mínimos:

```
max <- pmax(datos2$col1, datos2$col2)
min <- pmin(datos2$col1, datos2$col2)

datos2$col1 <- min
datos2$col2 <- max
```

Comment: Patricio, eres mi héroe. No hay ni una pregunta de R que se te escape.